# Error when generating new angular app in Nx workspace

Tags: angular, nrwl, angular-schematics, nx-workspace

We're getting the following error when trying to generate an Angular app in an Nx workspace following an upgrade from Angular/Nx 12->14:

```
SchematicsException [Error]: Project "name-of-app" does not exist.
```

The command we're using is:

```
npx nx g @nrwl/angular:application name-of-app
```

Looking into the source code, the error seems to happen when the component generator is called. We have written a custom schematic for the component generator but I'm not sure why that would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was a type mismatch in our component generator code for Tree. It turns out that @compodoc/compodoc was bringing in v13.x.x for @angular-devkit/schematics when we were on Angular 14. Since it was the first dep to require schematics, its version overrode the other versions. The fix was to force schematics to v14 by including it in our package.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/schematics@^14.2.7
// this step may or may not be required
npm install --save-dev @schematics/angular@^14.2.7
```